# A twisted self-dual subgroup lattice

Tags: gr.group-theory, lattice-theory

A lattice $(X,\le)$ is **twisted self-dual** iff it is self-dual but there is not any self-duality $f:X\to X$ with $f\circ f=1_X$.

Is there any group with lattice of all its subgroups twisted self-dual?

Comment: The work of Pogel is related.